# Framing on top of a half brick wall

Tags: framing, metal

I am designing a greenhouse and would like to create a 3ft brick wall, with metal framing on top where I can install various windows. I have included a picture of the general structure I am trying to replicate. I am just confused about what sort of metal I would even use for this. I have am understanding of framing wood walls but not metal walls. Do you still frame 16 inches O.C? Will that be strong enough to hold the roof? Do i just use a brad nailer to connect the metal and brick? Obviously people do this all the time, I guess I am just a bit confused and could use any advice!

I would be using generic cement bricks.

[image: greenhouse]

Comment: Would never use a brad nailer for that.  You will want bolts and drills.  The picture you show, that building was done with engineers to design, it is not something a backyard DIYer should attempt, and I do not think there are decent plans easy to find for metal buildings.  Wood building plans are a dime a dozen. My suggestion is to find a maker of metal greenhouses and buy a kit from them or go with wood.  Using any nailer will only put one or both your eyes out from the nails bouncing off the metal/brick.

Comment: That's fair, I am a homesteader however and have built many structures, just never metal on concrete! I have used a brad nailer to successfully frame a wood wall into a cement wall, so I just thought this might work in a similar way. Is it because the nailer would not go through the metal? I am very passionate about not being reliant on any company for kits, I am also happy to use something other than brick if you had any good ideas! Just in the very beginning stages of design at this point and just toying with the idea of brick as it is easily accessible and looks decent but not set on it!

Comment: There are nailers for place nails into cement, but my idea of a brad nailer is one mainly for nailing trim with small nails.  Attaching metal(steel) together is by welding(good welds) or bolts.  It can be done, but you do need a decent idea of metal work to use the right(strong enough) sizes of steel tubing/squares for the local conditions of wind and snow.  To attach to the brick/cement do suggest anchor bolts in the cement, then the right measurements to drill the holes in the metal base plates.

Comment: I was considering wood at first, but where I live the only good long-term outdoor wood is cedar, and at $16 for a 2×4×8 it's just not do-able for the size of greenhouse that I need. So I thought maybe brick for the first three feet, then I would install a basic frame with metal, then install windows as I collect them for free. The picture I provided is just a very general idea of what i would like to accomplish

Comment: My boyfriend is a pipe fitter do you think he would be good to ask about this? I didn't think so because I didn't associate pipes with knowledge about metal but maybe he would know something?

Comment: Thank you! I will look into Anchor bolts for sure!

Comment: A pipe fitter should have or knows someone who does.  Unless you can get second hand steel, might not be that happy with steel prices either.  Will probably want 3x3 steel for main supports, 1 1/2 or 2 inch for the in between pieces.

Comment: Just realized I said brad nailer which is definitely not what I used to frame the wall! It was actually a framing nailer that i used, my bad!